# Intent for for storage explorer in Marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-external-storage

In Android 6.0 Marshmallow there is a a storage explorer under Settings → Storage & USB → Explore.

Is it possible to launch this `Activity` from within an app using an `Intent`?

I discovered I can launch the [Settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) activity with [`ACTION_INTERNAL_STORAGE_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_INTERNAL_STORAGE_SETTINGS) or [`ACTION_MEMORY_CARD_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MEMORY_CARD_SETTINGS) however I have not found a way to launch the "Explore" activity.
I would like to launch it in Explore mode with a predefined path, maybe via an intent extra or something, such as `intent.putExtra("PATH", getFilesDir() + "/stuff");`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INTERNAL_STORAGE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Is it possible to start any of the following?

- com.android.externalstorage
- com.android.documentsui
- com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity

Is it possible to start the activity with a predefined path?

Comment: which api level are you using?

Comment: @ivan, as stated in the post, Android 6.0 Marshmallow so that would be API level 23.

Comment: @fred Did you managed to open storage explorer under Settings → Storage & USB → Explore. ? Can you please post the code you used ?

Comment: I am able to figure this out .. startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.settings.Settings.ACTION_INTERNAL_STORAGE_SETTINGS)); That's it..!! Happy coding..!!

Answer (score 1):

> in Android 6.0, you can use Intent same as previous version of android
>   OS which open default storage explorer with recent files you can also
>   change its to ***show external storage*** using option menu there is
>   also navigation drawer for more options like photos,image,videos,Audio
>   filters etc. below is code

```
public void openFileEx() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 15);
    }
```

---

***but you have to ask for permission of `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in android 6.0 Marshmallow for read file from external storage like below***

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
                    openFileEx();
                } else {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestContactsPermissions();
                    } else {
                        openFileEx();
                    }
                }
```

---

```
public void requestContactsPermissions() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Log.i("PERMISIOM",
                    "Displaying contacts permission rationale to provide additional context.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    11);
        } else {
            // Contact permissions have not been granted yet. Request them directly.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 11);
        }
    }
```

---

*you can also check for more permission using above code, Here is sample of [android-RuntimePermissions](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions) on Github.*

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code of the [`DocumentsActivity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/packages/DocumentsUI/src/com/android/documentsui/DocumentsActivity.java) class is useful.

Launching the activity can be done this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setClassName("com.android.documentsui", "com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```